# SSL Errors when uploading py file to proxy server via Twine

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, pypi, twine

I have packaged up a python application using `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`on an Ubuntu machine.

I want to upload these files to a proxy server of Artifactory. I am using the following twine command to do it

`twine upload --repository-url https://apro.example.net.au/api/pypi/example-python -u username -p password dist/* --client-cert /usr/lib/ssl/certs/my_cert.pem`

When I run the command I am getting the following error
`SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='apro.example.net.au', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/pypi/example-python (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(336265225, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2959)'),))`

I have placed my `my_certs.pem` into `/usr/lib/ssl/certs/` and ran `update-ca-certificates` to make sure the certificates are up to date.

When I was trying to figure out what the SSLError was I came across what line it was complaining in `_ssl.c` in `cpython` (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_ssl.c)

What does `SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_OK` exact mean? I cannot figure out what is wrong with the certificate as it works fine with other applications I run against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my proxy server of Artifactory was having issues with certificates